# How to keep k most similar term records for each term and replace the less similar ones with 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe like this.

[image: term by term matrix]

It is a  term by term similarity matrix.For a nxn term by term similarity matrix,I want to keep k records which is the most similarity term records for each term and replace the rest of n-k less similar records with 0. For this toy example, I want to get a dataframe like
[image: this]

if k=2.

```
frame=pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[1,0.5,3,0.3],[0.5,1,0.3,0.4],[3,0.3,1,0.7],[0.3,0.4,0.7,1]]),columns=['w1','w2','w3','w4'])
frame.index=['w1','w2','w3','w4']
```

Could you tell me how to code this functionality with pandas when applying it to big matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach making use of [`NumPy's advanced indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) and [`np.argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) for selecting and resetting appropriate number of elements per row -

```
k = 2 # no. of records to keep
a = frame.values # Extract the values as an array view
n = a.shape[1] - k # no. of elements to be reset per row
idx = np.argpartition(a,n,axis=1)[:,:n] # smallest n column indices per row
a[np.arange(idx.shape[0])[:,None], idx] = 0 # reset those in array/dataframe
```

Sample run -

```
In [478]: frame=pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[1,0.5,0.2,0.3],[0.5,1,0.3,0.4],\
     ...:   [0.2,0.3,1,0.7],[0.3,0.4,0.7,1]]),columns=['w1','w2','w3','w4'])
     ...: frame.index=['w1','w2','w3','w4']
     ...: 

In [479]: frame
Out[479]: 
     w1   w2   w3   w4
w1  1.0  0.5  0.2  0.3
w2  0.5  1.0  0.3  0.4
w3  0.2  0.3  1.0  0.7
w4  0.3  0.4  0.7  1.0

## After code run with k=2

In [481]: frame
Out[481]: 
     w1   w2   w3   w4
w1  1.0  0.5  0.0  0.0
w2  0.5  1.0  0.0  0.0
w3  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.7
w4  0.0  0.0  0.7  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
frame.where(frame.isin(frame.stack().sort_values(ascending=False).unique()[:k+1]), 0.0)
Out[88]: 
     w1   w2   w3   w4
w1  1.0  0.5  0.0  0.0
w2  0.5  1.0  0.0  0.0
w3  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.7
w4  0.0  0.0  0.7  1.0
```

Explanations:

- Extract all unique values in your correlation matrix
- keep the unique values sorted descending
- take k+1 first elements from that list; +1 counts to skip 1.0 diagonal value
- calculate the boolean matrix where the values matched your dataframe
- apply a where filter with 0.0 as false condition value